# Converting init file on Mac/Linux to Windows

Tags: init-file, microsoft-windows, directories, filenames

I use a package called `Deft` that needs a directory to store and load files. To define this directory on Mac or GNU/Linux I use the following expression:

```
(setq deft-directory "~/Dropbox/org")
```

When using `Emacs` on Windows shall I change every `~` to `C:\\Users\\sbac` and every `/` to `\\` as in:

```
(setq deft-directory "C:\\Users\\sbac\\Dropbox\\org")
```

Comment: Note that `M-: (expand-file-name "~/Dropbox/org")` will show you which path that expands to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Emacs on MS Windows uses the GNU/Unix conventions of `~` and `/` as directory separator, just fine.

See also the Emacs manual, nodes [Minibuffer File](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-File.html) and [Windows HOME](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html).

(And on MS Windows be sure to define environment variable `HOME`.)

Comment: OK. But when I use `(setq deft-directory "~/Dropbox/org")` and then `Alt-X Deft` I receive the message `Directory ~/Dropbox/org does not exist`. But this directory exists.

Comment: I have no idea what variable `deft-directory` is, or what command `Deft` is, which means the question is incomplete. Did you perhaps mean standard variable `default-directory`?

Comment: I use a package called `Deft`. Anyway, reading your `Windows HOME` link I think that `Emacs` thinks that my home directory is different from `C:\Users\sbac`.

Comment: Yes, on MS Windows you will want to define environment variable `HOME`.

Comment: I have edited my post. How to define `HOME` on Windows is a subject of a different question.

Comment: May want to use expand-file-name https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Expansion.html